# Create an application plist

Tags: plist

What would a Mac OS X Application Info.plist file look like? I only need the bare minimum, so that I have:

- Launches an executable
- Has an icon

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

This is the real, bare minimum:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
  <string>ExecutableFileName</string>
  <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
  <string>AppIcon</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It is recommended to include a `CFBundleIdentifier` key also. This way the system can identify your application. I really recommend you include it.

---

You can find more keys in the [Information Property List Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009247).