# CPack for OSX Bundle Info.plist

Tags: macos, cmake, info.plist, cpack

I am building a small package for OSX using CPack. In the [CPack wiki](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:CPackPackageGenerators) it says I have to specify a `Info.plist` file, else the `make package` will fail.

`CPACK_BUNDLE_PLIST - path to a file that will become the bundle plist.`

However [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST.html) it says there is a way to automatically generate `Info.plist` file. Can anyone how to use that? Right now I am using an emtpy `Info.plist` file and it seems to be working, but not sure what will break in future due this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing `MACOSX_BUNDLE` with `CPACK_BUNDLE`. [Here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cpack/PackageGenerators#overview) is an explanation of the difference

> **Important Note:** Do **not** use the MACOSX_BUNDLE property on executables that will be packaged using the bundle-generator! Specifying MACOSX_BUNDLE creates a separate bundle for each individual executable at build-time; the structure of these bundles becomes redundant when the bundle generator consolidates multiple executables into a single bundle.

So `MACOSX_BUNDLE` does generate an `Info.plist` automatically, while `CPACK_BUNDLE` needs one specified in `CPACK_BUNDLE_PLIST`.

For answering your question on what `Info.plist` to specify, it's probably best to use a simple basic `Info.plist` that is not empty, similar to the one specified here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6323462/369009